# How To Generate a Random Number that is a multiple 3 in a Range in a Bash Script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I apologize if my title question is too broad. I am trying to generate a variable that is a random multiple of 3 between a certain range.

```
randomNumber= Multiple of 3 between 45 and 72
```

Comment: Pick a random number between 15 and 24, then multiply it by 3.

Comment: If you accept a very small bias of `1/429496730` in favour of `45`, `48`, `51`, `54`, `57` and `60`, try `(( randomNumber = 3 * (15 + $(hexdump -vn4 -e'"%u\n"' /dev/urandom) % 10) ))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has a builtin `RANDOM` <sup>(0 ~ 32767)</sup> var. If you have Bash 5.1+, there's also `SRANDOM` <sup>(0 ~ 4294967295)</sup>.

```
[Bash-5.2] % echo $(( 3 * (15 + RANDOM % 10) ))
51
[Bash-5.2] % echo $(( 3 * (15 + RANDOM % 10) ))
57
[Bash-5.2] % echo $(( 3 * (15 + RANDOM % 10) ))
48
```

Comment: How would I change the min and max? Say if I had to change 45 to 3 and 72 to 9?

Comment: @dandex200 you'd write `echo $(( 3 * (1 + RANDOM % 3) ))`. Basically : `RANDOM % X` generates a value between 0 and X-1. You can also use variables to change your ranges dynamically. To generate a value between 3 and 9 : `min=1; max=3; echo $(( 3 * (min + RANDOM % max) ))`

Comment: @dandex200 If you want something completely modulable, you can also write `multiple=3; min=45; max=72; echo $(( multiple * (min / multiple + RANDOM % ( (max - min) / multiple + 1)) ))`

Comment: @dandex200 the logic is quite simple: 15 = 45/3; 10 = (72/3 - 45/3) + 1